# knockout : observable count value depending on a function

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Suppose I have an observable array

```
[{type:'red' , value:1},
{type:'blue' , value:'2'},
{type:'red' , value:3},
{type:'red' , value:4}]
```

Now I need an observable value which returns the count form array with type == red
and this count updated every time on any change in object of the observable array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a computed obervable here, something like this will work (untested):

```
var yourArray = ko.observableArray([]);

var count = ko.computed(function() {
    var items = ko.utils.arrayFilter(yourArray(), function(item) {
         return item.type == "red";
    });

    return items.length;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply chris. 
As I am new to knockout , so can u plz tell how can I get this count in data-bind text. 
I tried it by replacing var count with this.count = the function 
and <span data-bind="text:count"></span> in html but it's returning the function itself.

Comment: In fact, try... text: count() instead.

Comment: I think this should be `var count = ko.computed(function()....`   Then you just have `<span data-bind="text:count"></span>`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ko.computed`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) to do this.

Example viewmodel:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.arrayOfObjects= ko.observableArray( [{type:'red' , value:1},{type:'blue' , value:'2'},{type:'red' , value:3},{type:'red' , value:4}]);

    self.count = ko.computed(function() {
        var redItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.arrayOfObjects(), function(arrayItem) {
             return arrayItem.type == 'red';
        });

        return redItems.length;
    });
}
```

Anything bound to count will have it's value change as the number of red elements changes:

```
 <span data-bind="text: count"></span>
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/Wmb47/2/

Comment: @kishal Np, feel free to click on the tick by my answer to accept this one if it helped you.